# Tiny Slider 2 two rows of cards

Tags: javascript, css, layout, carousel

I am using tiny-slider 2. I am trying to have two rows of cards on one page.
As I have read here https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider/issues/433 the author is suggesting to make two lines as one big slide.

My html code right now is:

```
<div class="slider_wrapper">
                <div id='attraction_slider' class="attraction_slider">
                    <div>
                        <!-- Cards added dynamically > 
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <!-- Cards added dynamically > 
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

However when I do this I get the following result:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```js
var slider = tns({
            container: '.my-slider',
            items: 1,
            responsive: {
                1: {
                    edgePadding: 20,
                    gutter: 20,
                    items: 1,
                    mouseDrag: true
                },
                700: {
                    gutter: 30,
                    mouseDrag: true
                },
                900: {
                    items: 1,
                    mouseDrag: true
                }
            }
        });
```

```css
.card {
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            /* width: 300px; */
        }
        .card > img {
            height: 200px;
        }
        
        .card:hover {
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        
        .container {
            padding: 2px 16px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/tiny-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>Hello there! How are you?</h1>
    <div class="my-slider">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                    <p>Interior Designer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar">
                <div class="container">
                    <h4><b>Jane Doe</b></h4>
                    <p>Interior Designer</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar">
            <div class="container">
                <h4><b>John Doe</b></h4>
                <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For me, it is working fine.
I think you are calling `tns` before your cards are loaded. In the ReadMe file, there is a warning given at the beginning itself, I am pasting it here.

***Warning:** tiny-slider works with static content and it works in the browser only. If the HTML is loaded dynamically, make sure to call `tns()` after its loading.*

Please make sure if you are calling `tns` after all your cards are loaded.